# Visual Studio 2022 loading window freezes and the program does not open further. Any Ideas?

Tags: visual-studio

I faced with a problem.

**Short prehistory:**
I was scripting on Rage MP Api on C# (GTA V RP servers)
One day I decided to run the programm and everything was going normal.
But then I closed the Console Window, however Visual Studio execution buttons stayed
inactive. I tried to close VS, but it typed me to stop the programm execution first.
So I decided to close VS through Task Manager. And after that i got this problem.

By the way firstly when I tried open VS It closed immediately.
But when I tried to restore VS I got notification (.NET Core 3.1 no longer supported) and removed package from installation. Then the loading window started to freeze and never open VS.

It can be usefull, that while scripting I got this error **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe , Version=6.0.0.0** and to solve this I did this command
`gacutil /i System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` Anyway it didnt help

And VS does not give any errors

**What I tried:**

1. Restore and reinstall
2. Delete related folders and reinstall (not sure if deleted all)
3. Сhanging environment variables (actually moved some path up and added new one)
4. Added new rule to AppLocker
5. `Devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`
6. Install Microsoft VS/.Net Log Collection Tool (but I didnt understand anything)
7. Run VS as administrator

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You didn't say anything about the visual studio version. Update it to the latest version, now it's 17.5.0. You can look at similar issues https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio?q=freez+on+load+visual+studio+2022 and, if updating to the latest version does not help, open feedback on your issue.

Comment: I updated it through VS Installe, as well as deleted it with Installer and downloaded it again